# how to install amazon-linux-extras on EC2 Ubuntu 18.0

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-18.04

I tried `sudo apt-get amazon-linux-extras` 
It is ubuntu, so I don't have `yum` on the machine and I can't find the repo to download  `amazon-linux-extras`

**EDIT**
I am trying to run `make` to build cpp code base and I get following error

```
/bin/sh: 2: autoreconf: not found
```